EventTarget doesn't work in Firefox content script, does work in Chrome
In Chrome extension content scripts it is fine to do:
const myTarget = new EventTarget()
myTarget.addEventListener('test', () => console.log('test1'))
myTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'))

but this does not work in Firefox, because in Firefox this !== window. Instead Firefox has this === globalThis where for some reason some standard Web API's like EventTarget in globalThis['EventTarget'] do not work, while window['EventTarget'] does work.
As a result this would mean to be able to use various standard Web APIs like EventTarget I'd need to call them via Window as window['EventTarget'] even though it works fine in Chrome as is. Alternatively deleting the EventTarget with delete globalThis['EventTarget'] makes it fallback to window['EvenTarget'] as well. I don't think either solutions are acceptable.
How can I deal with this in a sane way?
Example:
const { log } = console

log(EventTarget === EventTarget)
log(EventTarget === window['EventTarget'])
log(EventTarget === globalThis['EventTarget'])
log(EventTarget === self['EventTarget'])

const test1 = new EventTarget()
const test2 = new window['EventTarget']()
const test3 = new globalThis['EventTarget']()

test1.addEventListener('test', () => log('test1'))
test2.addEventListener('test', () => log('test2'))
test3.addEventListener('test', () => log('test3'))

test1.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'))
test2.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'))
test3.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'))

will log in Firefox add-on content script:
true
false
true
false
test2

and in Chrome extension content script:
true
true
true
true
test1
test2
test3

Firefox version: 128 (Latest)
Firefox manifest version: v2
Chrome manifest version: v3

It's a bug in Firefox, so any attempt to use the affected API would be hacky. You can write your own event emitter or use an existing one, the simplest one is like 10 lines of code.

Conclusion is, as @woxxom mentioned, that it's yet another decade old bug in Firefox that never got fixed. Instead of reinventing standard Web API's for this by coding it ourselves, it suffices to:
globalThis['EventTarget'] = window['EventTarget']

or
delete globalThis['EventTarget']

for Firefox only, as unsightly as it is.
